# Put the website icon on each image uploaded

Tags: django, image-processing, file-upload

In my Django application users can upload images to be displayed on the website. I need a way to mark these images with the website icon upon upload but I can't seem to think of any way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a water-mark.
When a images is uploaded you would water-mark it and then save it

If you are using the Pillow Library,
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_creating_a_watermark.htm

https://medium.com/better-programming/add-copyright-or-watermark-to-photos-using-python-a3773c71d431

Comment: Thank you! That's precisely what I was looking for.